# how to enable cyclomatic complexity in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

how to enable cyclomatic complexity for a java code in sonarqube? currently am using sonarqube 6.2.

I want the CC value in dashboard of the java project

Answer (score 2):

You can see the Cyclomatic Complexity value for your project on its Measures page. It is the "Complexity" value. It does not appear on the project home page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ann. But am able to see the complexity value (of function, file & class) in measures tab. where can I get the cyclomatic complexity value?

Comment: See my expansion @Raji

Comment: Thanks Ann for your response:)

Answer (score 1):

1 - you can add the complexity widget on your dashboard project
2 - for more details on a file, you can browse the code on your project with the 'code' tab in the menu, chosse the source file you want and select 'more actions' -> 'show measures', then a pop-in will show many measures with complexity

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bernard.
But am able to see the complexity value (of function, file & class) in measures tab. where i can get the cyclomatic complexity value?